# How to check a .txt file for text and give an error message if blank

Tags: python

I have a program that reads numbers from a `.txt` file, the numbers are separated by a coma, and the program assigns them to variables to work out quadratic equations. I need to know what different ways I can check the file for txt, and display an error message.

I currently have the program working fine, it does check for text and gives an error message (`The text file is empty`)if the file is blank. However somewhere in my code I have stuffed up, because if there is text in the file and the program does its equations, it also gives the error message. I know somewhere I have muddled up my loops.

Here is the code, without the functions:

```
# Main Program
userInput = True
while userInput == True :
    file = input("\nPlease input text file name: ")
    file = file + ".txt"
    if os.path.exists(file):
        with open(file, "rt") as text_file:
            for line in text_file: 
                a,b,c = [float(i.strip()) for i in line.split(',')]
                if a == 0:
                    count = count + 1
                    print("\nEquation No.", count)
                    print("a =", a," b =", b," c =", c)
                    print("Cannot be a quadratic equation if 'a' is zero")
                else:
                    count = count + 1
                    print("\nEquation No. ", count)
                    print("a =", a," b =", b," c =", c)
                    equationroots(a, b, c)
            else:
                userInput = False
                if userInput == False:
                    print("\nThe text file is empty")
                    break
    else:
        print("\nThe file cannot be found")
        continue
input("\nEnd")
```

And here is the output, with just two lines in a `.txt` file:

```
Welcome

Please input text file name: test1

Equation No. 1
a = 0.0  b = 2.0  c = 4.0
Cannot be a quadratic equation if 'a' is zero

Equation No.  2
a = 3.0  b = 7.0  c = 12.0
There are two distinct complex Roots
-1.1667  + i 9.7468
-1.1667  - i 9.7468

The text file is empty

End
```

As you can see in the output, I am still getting the error message. I would appreciate any input in solving my problem. Thanks

Comment: You're using a `for else` loop, therefore once the for loop is done, `The text file is empty` will *always* be printed. There is no check here for if the file is empty.

Comment: Have a look at section 4.4 [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) for more details about a `for-else` loop - the else part always runs unless you "break" out of the inner loop. "Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the iterable (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `else` statement doesn't do what you want it to after the `for line in text_file:` bit. Here's your code currently:

```
with open(file, "rt") as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        #some code that analyses the file and prints some output data

    # this else statement is getting triggered regardless of if the 'for' loop runs or not
    else:
        userInput = False
        if userInput == False:
            print("\nThe text file is empty")
            break
```

one way to fix this is to create a boolean that gets set to some value if you enter the for loop:

```
# Main Program
while userInput == True:
    # reset this to True every new loop of the parent while loop
    empty = True
    # ...
    if os.path.exists(file):
        with open(file, "rt") as text_file:
            for line in text_file:
                # the for loop was entered, don't print the empty file error message
                empty = False
                # ...
            # only run this if the 'for' loop hasn't been run this iteration of the parent 'while' loop    
            if empty:
                userInput = False
                if userInput == False:
                    print("\nThe text file is empty")
                    break
    # ...
```

(`# ...` signifies code that was cut out because it's not relevant to the point I'm making)

Answer (score 0):

- Any time there's a section of code that you'll be repeating a lot, it's good to use a function.
- Here I'm checking if the file is literally empty, a single white-space wouldn't count as empty.
- You never change your `a,b,c` to integers, so `a == 0` will never be true.

```
def output_equation(count, a, b, c):
    print("\nEquation No.", count)
    print("a =", a," b =", b," c =", c)
    if a == 0:
        print("Cannot be a quadratic equation if 'a' is zero")
    else:
        equationroots(a, b, c)
    return count + 1

count = 0
while True:
    file = input("\nPlease input text file name, or press Enter to exit: ")
    if not file:
        break
    file = file + ".txt"
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        print("\nThe file cannot be found.")
        continue
    if not os.path.getsize(file):
        print("\nThe file is empty.")
        continue
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f: 
            a,b,c = map(int, line.split(','))
            count = output_equation(count, a, b, c)

print("\nEnd")
```

Comment: `lines = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]` is ridiculously wasteful and unnecessary; it reads the whole file into a `list` of the lines (`f.readlines()`, which is 100% superfluous since you just iterate it and discard it), then makes *another* `list` of all the lines without leading/trailing whitespace (only to iterate it once and discard it). Just do `for line in f:` and have the first line of the loop do `line = line.strip()`, and you'll only need peak memory proportionate to the longest line, not twice the total size of the file.

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant, that makes sense. There isn't actually any reason to hold the whole file in memory period. @ShadowRanger

Comment: Also, if the values are integers, then extra whitespace doesn't matter when converting them, so using `strip()` at all isn't necessary. @ShadowRanger

Answer (score -2):

I think the best way to check if the file is empty, is with a [guard clause](https://medium.com/lemon-code/guard-clauses-3bc0cd96a2d3). We can read the contents of the file right after opening it. This way if we read the value (and strip the whitespace) and the content is blank, we can immediately break from the while loop and inform the user that the file is empty.

To check if the file exists or not, I think using a guard clause here as well, will definitely help with your readability. Let me know if that helped.

```py
import os

# Main Program
userInput = True
while userInput == True :
    file = input("\nPlease input text file name: ")
    file += ".txt"

    if not os.path.exists(file):
        print("\nThe file cannot be found")
        continue

    with open(file, "rt") as text_file:
        if text_file.read().strip() == "":
            print("\nThe text file is empty")
            break

        # Move text cursor to the beginning of file
        text_file.seek(0)

        for line in text_file: 
            a, b, c = [float(i.strip()) for i in line.split(',')]
            if a == 0:
                count += 1
                print("\nEquation No.", count)
                print("a =", a," b =", b," c =", c)
                print("Cannot be a quadratic equation if 'a' is zero")
            else:
                count += 1
                print("\nEquation No. ", count)
                print("a =", a," b =", b," c =", c)
                equationroots(a, b, c)

input("\nEnd")
```

Comment: I believe the cursor will be moved to the end of the file when you do `text_file.read()`, meaning the later attempt to do `for line in text_file:` will always fail since there isn't anything left to read.

Comment: This has the problem of looping back to ```Input file name:``` instead of following on from the ```for line in text_file:```

Comment: Yeah @BeRT2me, you're right about that, I think that can be solved using the seek function.

Comment: I think this will now be functional, but I'd try only reading the first couple of bytes to check if it's empty, otherwise you're wasting a lot of time reading in the whole file. `if text_file.read(10).strip() == "":`